# Can I Use Only One RecyclerView For The Three Different CardView With Different Design?

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, android-cardview

**Can I create only one `recycler_view.xml` to handle my three set of `cardview.xml` with different design?** Or Do I need to create separate `recyclerView` for each one of my `cardViews`.

For example I have different `CardView` for `News, Activities and Groups`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes we can use multiple cardView.
For reference see below link
[Sample Adapter](https://github.com/subbuboyapati/MovieMasti/blob/master/app/src/main/java/com/subbu/moviemasti/adapter/ReviewAdapter.java)

Here i am showing list of reviews when no reviews i am displaying no reviews availble. Here i am creating 2 ViewHolders one for my review item and another one for no review available item.

code:

```
package com.subbu.moviemasti.adapter;

import android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.TextView;

import com.subbu.moviemasti.R;
import com.subbu.moviemasti.entities.Review;
import com.subbu.moviemasti.fragment.IReviewView;

import java.util.List;

import butterknife.Bind;
import butterknife.ButterKnife;

/**
 * Created by subrahmanyam on 24-12-2015.
 */
public class ReviewAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<RecyclerView.ViewHolder> {
    private final List<Review> results;

    public ReviewAdapter(IReviewView reviewFragment, List<Review> results) {
        this.results = results;
    }

    @Override
    public RecyclerView.ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        View view = null;
        RecyclerView.ViewHolder viewHolder = null;
        switch (viewType) {
            case 0:
                view = View.inflate(parent.getContext(), R.layout.list_item_empty_view, null);
                viewHolder = new EmptyViewHolder(view);
                break;
            case 1:
                view = View.inflate(parent.getContext(), R.layout.review_list_item, null);
                viewHolder = new ViewHolder(view);
                break;
        }
        return viewHolder;
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(RecyclerView.ViewHolder holder, int position) {
        int viewType = getItemViewType(position);
        switch (viewType) {
            case 0:
                EmptyViewHolder emptyViewHolder = (EmptyViewHolder) holder;
                emptyViewHolder.emptyView.setText(((EmptyViewHolder) holder).emptyView.getResources().getString(R.string.no_trailers));
                break;
            case 1:
                Review review = results.get(position);
                ViewHolder viewHolder = (ViewHolder) holder;
                viewHolder.userName.setText(review.getAuthor());
                viewHolder.review.setText(review.getContent());
                break;
        }
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return results.size() > 0 ? results.size() : 1;
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemViewType(int position) {
        return results.size() == 0 ? 0 : 1;
    }

    class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
        @Bind(R.id.review_user)
        TextView userName;
        @Bind(R.id.review_review)
        TextView review;

        public ViewHolder(View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            ButterKnife.bind(this, itemView);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 5):

Yes you can use `getItemViewType()`

Depending upon view type inflate different layout for item

> Example

```
public class MyAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<RecyclerView.ViewHolder> {
    class ViewHolder0 extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
        ...
    }

    class ViewHolder2 extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
        ...
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemViewType(int position) {

        return viewType;
    }

    @Override
    public RecyclerView.ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
         switch (viewType) {
             case 0: return new ViewHolder0(...);
             case 2: return new ViewHolder2(...);
             ...
         }
    }
}
```