# How to use multiple layout using one RecyclerView Adapter?

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, android-adapter, cardview

Hey guys I'm implementing two cards in an recyclerview and also created two view holder but didn't get the code for adapter help me guys.

```
public class ViewHolder1 extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

    private TextView Chatin;

    public ViewHolder1(View v) {
        super(v);
        Chatin = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.Chatin);
    }

    public TextView getChatin() {
        return Chatin;
    }

    public void setChatin(TextView chatin) {
        this.Chatin = chatin;
    }


}
```

Other view holder is same as it is.

Comment: Please refer the url http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25914003/recyclerview-and-handling-different-type-of-row-inflation might be helpful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes we can use multiple cardView. For reference see below link for Sample Adapter :-https://github.com/subbuboyapati/MovieMasti/blob/master/app/src/main/java/com/subbu/moviemasti/adapter/ReviewAdapter.java

This answer also help you. [Can I Use Only One RecyclerView For The Three Different CardView With Different Design?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35267543/can-i-use-only-one-recyclerview-for-the-three-different-cardview-with-different)

Have a look at this tutorial also, http://arjunu.com/2015/10/android-recyclerview-with-different-cardviews/ .

Comment: links provided are very helpful.

Comment: Glad, It helped you.

Answer (score 3):

You can display multiple cards in Recycler view.

**1) Override getItemViewType() method**

```
@Override
public int getItemViewType(int position) {

    switch (position) {
        case 0:
            return VIEW_TYPE_ONE;
        case 1:
            return VIEW_TYPE_TWO;
             .
             .
             .
        case n:
            return VIEW_TYPE_N;

        default:
            return DEFAULT_VIEW_TYPE;
    }
}
```

**2)Check for viewType in onCreateViewHolder() method**

```
 @Override
 public RecyclerView.ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
   switch (viewType) {
     case  VIEW_TYPE_ONE: 
      // return card one.  
          .
          .
          .
    }
 }
```

**3) Check for view type in onBindViewHolder() with the position and set data to your card accordingly.**

```
@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(RecyclerView.ViewHolder holder, int position) {
     switch (getItemViewType(position)) {
        case VIEW_TYPE_ONE:
          ViewTypeOneViewHolder holderObj= (ViewTypeOneViewHolder) holder;
          //Your implementation for view type one.

          break;
          .
          .
          .
     }
 }
```